# Back-end updates with changes made via inline editing on ExtJS Summary Grid?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, lotus

While I am trying to track changes made via inline editing on ExtJS Grid (with SummaryGrouping), I want to know what is the best way to update the back-end which is domino database record.

Obviously I dont want to update on each and every edit but to see if there is a way the changes can be temporarily stored and later via a submit button can be updated on the back-end using agent etc.

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All changes the user has made while editing grid are stored locally at client in the grid store provided that the store is not configure with `autoSync:true`. For saving changes, you need to have a button with handler that would call

```
 store.sync()
```

manually. See that store has a valid proxy and writer configured.

See also [this example](http://extjs.eu/ext-examples/#writable-grid)

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am giving it a try and would get back to you @saki.